# What are the characteristics of daemons?

Tags: a-discovery-of-witches

In the series *A Discovery of Witches*, the three main groups of supernatural creatures are daemons, witches, and vampires. The protagonist and deuteragonist belong to the latter two groups, so they are described in some detail. Vampires are ageless with considerable strength, durability, speed, and perception, with the ability to take memories through drinking blood, along with some other potential powers. Witches have a wide variety of supernatural powers, with mental and elemental abilities standing out.

As for daemons, I seem to recall only some statements suggesting that they had prophetic dreams or visions. But then, "daemon" would seem a strange name for an entity with only those abilities: a more typical word would be "seer" or "oracle."

What are the capabilities or traits of daemons in *A Discovery of Witches*?

Comment: Broadly speaking, I think of them as extra-creative people who have a tendency to consider reality to be optional. I agree, though, that "demon" is not really the right word to encapsulate that, even if you spell it "daemon".

Comment: according to Wikipedia: Daimon or Daemon originally referred to a lesser deity or guiding spirit